# MVC iOs & Android Framework, what You preffer and Why?

Tags: iphone, android, frameworks, mobile

**Hello,
I would like to find any easy and strong mobile framework.

I working in phonegap, but i dont think that is good choice for biggest apps.
I would like something MVC and Easy.

I thinking about Rhomobile Rhodes, Appcelerator and WebView.

I Would like views in HTML5, but compile to native app.

Rhomobile Rhodes seems good, but is for Ruby and I like to preffer languge what I know..Javascript, PHP.

Is not something like CakePHP, but for JS?**

Thanks for You advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best choice is to use the preferred tools for the platform you wish to deploy against. For iOS apps this means using Xcode and iOS, for Android apps this means using Java and your choice of IDE. While there are any number of tools the allow you to bridge the differences between the two major mobile platforms (e.g., Pyxis) you are tying your future success to their future success. Should they fail, you fail.

MVC is a concept that you can employ regardless of the tool set used. Granted some frameworks do most of the heavy lifting for you, but you can follow the pattern's tenants (or not) with or without framework support.

Best way to determine which of the tools you list will meet your needs is to build a demo app with each (preferably the same app with the same functionality) tool. That way you can fully evaluate which best suits you.